# Is there a way in Swift to only recieve a specific element of a dictionary object from a JSON API?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a quiz app, where the user will see one group of answers to choose, where all the groups are pulled from a JSON API. As of now, all of the answer data is being shown in my preview, but all I want is a specific one, for example the second grouping, so all that would come through would be ("tonight", "tomorrow", "this week", "this month"). The answer variables are answer1, answer2, answer3, and answer4. Here is the link to the api to show the data I am using:
https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/641f82dcace6f33a22fbec99

Here is all the code I am using, which generates all the answer data:

```
import Foundation
    import SwiftUI


    struct ContentView: View {
        @StateObject var model = DataManager()
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                if let qData = model.response?.record.questiondata.data {
                    List(Array(qData.keys), id: \.self) { key in
                        VStack {
                            Text(qData[key]?.answer1.text ?? "no data")
                            Text(qData[key]?.answer2.text ?? "no data")
                            Text(qData[key]?.answer3.text ?? "no data")
                            Text(qData[key]?.answer4.text ?? "no data")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .task {
                await model.loadData()
            }
        }
    }

    @MainActor
    class DataManager: ObservableObject  {
        @Published var response: APIResponse? = nil
        
        func loadData() async  {
            if let url = URL(string: "https://api.jsonbin.io/v3/b/641f82dcace6f33a22fbec99") {
                do {
                    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
                    response = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

    struct APIResponse: Codable {
        let record: Record
        let metadata: Metadata
    }

    struct Metadata: Codable {
        let id: String
        let metadataPrivate: Bool
        let createdAt: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case id
            case metadataPrivate = "private"
            case createdAt
        }
    }

    struct Record: Codable {
        let questiondata: QuestionData
    }

    struct QuestionData: Codable {
        var data: [String : Quest]
        
        struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
            var stringValue: String
            var intValue: Int?
            
            init?(stringValue: String) {  self.stringValue = stringValue  }
            init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
        }
        
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            self.data = [:]
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyKey.self)
            container.allKeys.forEach { key in
                if let theQuest = try? container.decode(Quest.self, forKey: key) {
                    self.data[key.stringValue] = theQuest
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

    struct Quest: Codable {
        let question: String
        let answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4: Answer
    }

    struct Answer: Codable {
        let logo, text: String

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case logo
            case text = "Text"
        }
    }

    struct ContentView_Preview: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this setup using a simple `if`, to display just the specific data you want.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = DataManager()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let qData = model.response?.record.questiondata.data {
                
                // --- here
                if let theAnswers = qData["q1"] {
                    VStack {
                        Text(theAnswers.answer1.text)
                        Text(theAnswers.answer2.text)
                        Text(theAnswers.answer3.text)
                        Text(theAnswers.answer4.text)
                    }
                }

                // or this
                // if let theAnswers = model.response?.record.questiondata.data["q1"] {
                  // VStack {
                  //  Text(theAnswers.answer1.text)
                  //  Text(theAnswers.answer2.text)
                  //  Text(theAnswers.answer3.text)
                  // Text(theAnswers.answer4.text)
                // }
        }


                
                // alternatively
//                List(Array(qData.keys), id: \.self) { key in
//                    if key == "q1" {
//                        VStack {
//                            Text(qData[key]?.answer1.text ?? "no data")
//                            Text(qData[key]?.answer2.text ?? "no data")
//                            Text(qData[key]?.answer3.text ?? "no data")
//                            Text(qData[key]?.answer4.text ?? "no data")
//                        }
//                    }
//                }
            }
        }
        .task {
            await model.loadData()
        }
    }
}
```